# export tilesets at specified zoom levels from Mapbox

Tags: export, style, mapbox

I have created a style with Mapbox. I would like to export the tilesets at specified zoom levels. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I have tried downloading the .json code, but I do not know with what other application to read it.

Comment: What would you like to do with it? Mapbox hosts tiles so you can use them in web apps. You would need to host them yourself or find a different provider that hosts them for you.

Answer (score 2):

Go into Studio > click on a layer > Select Data.
You can see on the screenshot below that you can set zoom min/max per layer.

[image]

Comment: Does that mean that I have to do as you indicated for each layer? Also, will the tiles be exportable?

Comment: I believe so, can't use Select Data on multiple layer selections. You can download them from your Home page. These are vector tiles though, different than the TileMill tiles.

Comment: You don't to change them all if for example you want to restrict your map to a metro area. You would just use javascript to set minzoom for the whole map. That way you wouldn't need to change each layer in studio since javascript won't let you zoom out further.

Comment: As far as I understand, one cannot actually export MapBox tiles, unless within MapBox platforms.

Comment: You changed the question removing the zoom levels part of the question. So my answer no longer has anything to do with the question. If you have a new question, please post it separately to keep the integrity of the questions and answers on here.

Comment: You are right, Tim, and therefore I have back edited the question.